# alternating series convergence

Tags: calculus

find all value of $\alpha \in \Bbb R $ for which $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty { 1 + (-1)^n n^\alpha\over n^{2\alpha}}$$ converges (absolutely/conditionally).

let $$a_n = { 1 + (-1)^n n^\alpha\over n^{2\alpha}}$$

if $\alpha \le 0$ then $a_n$ diverges, hence the series diverges.

if $\alpha \gt 0$:

$${|a_n| \over {1 \over n^\alpha}} \le {{ 1 + n^\alpha\over n^{2\alpha}} \over {1 \over n^\alpha}} \le{n^\alpha  + n^{2\alpha} \over n^{2\alpha}} \to 1$$

so $|a_n|$ converges iff $\alpha > 1$

what can i do about $0\lt \alpha \le 1$?

Comment: Argue (conditional) convergence if $\alpha\gt 1/2$ and divergence if $\alpha\le 1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suppose that $0\lt \alpha\le 1$.  Consider the partial sum 
$$s_N=\sum_{1}^N \frac{1+(-1)^n n^\alpha}{n^{2\alpha}}=\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}+\sum_1^N (-1)^n \frac{1}{n^\alpha}.$$
Let 
$$u_N=\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}\quad\text{and}\quad  v_N=\sum_1^N (-1)^n \frac{1}{n^\alpha}.$$

If $\alpha \gt \frac{1}{2}$, the two sequences $(u_N)$ and $(v_N)$ both converge. The first converges because $2\alpha\gt 1$, and the second by the alternating series test. So $\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N$ exists, and our original series converges.

If $0\lt \alpha\le \frac{1}{2}$, the sequence $(v_N)$ is bounded by the Alternating Series Test, and the sequence $(u_N)$ is unbounded.  Thus if $0\lt \alpha\le \frac{1}{2}$, the partial sums $s_N$ are unbounded, and our original series diverges.

Comment: thank you. shame on me not seeing this :)

Comment: You are welcome. As to "not seeing," I am very competitive, and will claim that I have not seen many more things than you.